# HTTPS Connection error

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am trying to connect to a servlet from using`http url connection`,i.e http://localhost:9481/test/NewServlet. It worked fine for me. Now I want to connect using https://localhost:9481/test/NewServlet. I got the error like :

> Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long,Connection refused...

Do I need to edit anything in server.xml :

Presently it looks like:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Comment: You probably don't want SSL on the same port. The config you show has it running on port 8443.

Comment: Please give reply to my question

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use different port in your `server.xml` than in the test request. Try to hit `https://localhost:8443/test/NewServlet`

Answer (score 0):

8443 port in Tomcat is by default used for SSL connection.

I suggest you see tomcat documentation for SSL:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html
Hope this helps !

There is one more link that I found which could resolve your issue in no time:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes
This is an amazing article. Please go through to resolve the issue.